Why am I getting a "Non-nullable field '' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor error in a static class?
I wrote the following class:
internal class ClientInfo
{
    public string ClientID { get; set; } = "";
    public string UserName { get; set; } = "";
    public string Password { get; set; } = "";
    public string ServerName { get; set; } = "";
}

and then I tried to use it in the following static class:
public static class GetClinetUpdates
{
    internal static ClientInfo clinetInfo;

    public static async Task Run()
    {
        XDocument XMLRequest = CreateRequest();
        string soapServiceUrl = {url};
        var soapResponse = await SendSoapRequest(soapServiceUrl, XMLRequest);
        Console.WriteLine(soapResponse);
    }

    public static XDocument CreateRequest()
    {
        \\code to create the request, removed for simplicity 
        return createXMLRequest.GetRequest();
    }

    public static async Task<string> SendSoapRequest(string url, XDocument soapRequest)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            \\ request code, removed for simplicity
            return soapResponse;
        }
    }
}

The compiler is giving me the following warning:
Non-nullable field 'clinetInfo' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the field as nullable
Isn't this warning only meant for objects? Why am I getting it?

Your static class still has an implicit static constructor, and as ClientInfo has no assigned initial value (or isn't marked as nullable), you get the warning.

@MartinCostello thanks! I thought that because the static class is not being instantiated the compiler is not worried it exits the constructor without a value.
